# How can I convert a Guid to a Byte array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, guid, ascii

I have a service bus, and the only way to transform data is via JavaScript. I need to convert a Guid to a byte array so I can then convert it to Ascii85 and shrink it into a 20 character string for the receiving customer endpoint.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does it have to be in JavaScript? There is no native byte value.

Comment: Whatever you come up with will be hacky and awful in JavaScript, and scarcely worthy of an SO answer. A better question might be: "How do I improve my service architecture so I can transform data more robustly?"

Comment: The only scripting language the service bus supports is JavaScript. It is for sending Patient information VIA HL7 the product name is MIRTH and it is open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VERY old question but it shows up top of google search results so here is the new age correct answer.

```
Buffer.from(guid.replaceAll('-',''), 'hex')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (needs LOTS of tests):

```
var guid = "{12345678-90ab-cdef-fedc-ba0987654321}";
window.alert(guid + " = " + toAscii85(guid))

function toAscii85(guid)
{
    var ascii85  = ""
    var chars    = guid.replace(/\{?(?:(\w+)-?)\}?/g, "$1");
    var patterns = ["$4$3$2$1", "$2$1$4$3", "$1$2$3$4", "$1$2$3$4"];
    for(var i=0; i < 32; i+=8)
    {
        var block = chars.substr(i, 8)
            .replace(/(..)(..)(..)(..)/, patterns[i / 8]) //poorman shift
        var decValue = parseInt(block, 16);

        var segment = ""
        if(decValue == 0)
        {
            segment = "z"
        }
        else
        {
            for(var n = 4; n >= 0; n--)
            {
                segment = String.fromCharCode((decValue % 85) + 33) + segment;
                decValue /= 85;
            }
        }
        ascii85 += segment
    }
    return "<~" + ascii85 + "~>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the *unparse()* method in node-uuid package and its example here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uuid#uuid-unparse-buffer-offset