# Javascript convert GUID in string format into Base64

Tags: javascript, base64, guid

I'm in a client-side, javascript context.  I have a `GUID` in string format `e8b75aff-3422-4529-8a6a-15b33e674f48` and I need it in a`Base64` string `/1q36CI0KUWKahWzPmdPSA==`  How do I convert it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you encode to Base64 using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/246801/49186

Comment: How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058732/how-can-i-convert-a-guid-to-a-byte-array-in-javascript

Comment: Not exactly duplicate of the above 3. To convert a GUID to base64, we need to convert GUID to hex representation and then to base64.

Answer (score 17):

```js
// Convert GUID string to Base-64 in Javascript
// by Mark Seecof, 2012-03-31

var hexlist = '0123456789abcdef';
var b64list = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

// GUID string with four dashes is always MSB first,
// but base-64 GUID's vary by target-system endian-ness.
// Little-endian systems are far more common.  Set le==true
// when target system is little-endian (e.g., x86 machine).
//
function guid_to_base64(g, le) {
    var s = g.replace(/[^0-9a-f]/ig, '').toLowerCase();
    if (s.length != 32) return '';

    if (le) s = s.slice(6, 8) + s.slice(4, 6) + s.slice(2, 4) + s.slice(0, 2) +
      s.slice(10, 12) + s.slice(8, 10) +
      s.slice(14, 16) + s.slice(12, 14) +
      s.slice(16);
    s += '0';

    var a, p, q;
    var r = '';
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 33) {
      a = (hexlist.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 8) |
        (hexlist.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 4) |
        (hexlist.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)));

      p = a >> 6;
      q = a & 63;

      r += b64list.charAt(p) + b64list.charAt(q);
    }
    r += '==';

    return r;
  } // guid_to_base64()

//EDIT
function tryConversion() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = guid_to_base64(
    document.getElementById("input_guid").value,
    document.getElementById("cb_le").checked
  );
}
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div><label for="input_guid">GUID</label> <input type="text" maxlength="36" id="input_guid" value="83D95782-BDE4-466F-A490-46820D2B2CDC" />
</div>
<div><label for="cb_le">Little-Endian?</label> <input type="checkbox" id="cb_le" checked="checked" /></div>
<hr />
<div><button onclick="javascript:tryConversion()">Convert</button></div>
<div>Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
```