# javascript GUID base64 conversion doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, uuid, guid

I try to convert GUID in base64 string for some reasons in Node.js

My function is

```
function encode(guid) {
    let buffer = new Buffer(guid.replace(/-/g, ""), 'hex');
    let ret = buffer.toString('base64');
    ret = ret.replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/\+/g, "-");
    return ret.substring(0,22); //FIXME
}

function decode(encoded_string) {
    let buffer = new Buffer(encoded_string + '==', 'base64');
    let ret = buffer.toString('hex');
    ret = ret.replace(/_/g, "/").replace(/-/g, "+");
    return ret;
}
```

I tested with guid = 'c9a646d3-9c61-4cb7-bfcd-ee2522c8f633'

and the result was 'yaZG05xhTLe_ze4lIsj2Mw'

and also it has decoded well (without dash).

However, according to the http://guid-convert.appspot.com/

The converted result was '00amyWGct0y/ze4lIsj2Mw=='.

I believe I might did something wrong, but can't find what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javascript convert GUID in string format into Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095115/javascript-convert-guid-in-string-format-into-base64?rq=1)

You can check that your conversion is same as the result here when it is Big Endian, so I don't think it is a big problem.