# how to encode/decode ascii85 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, ascii85, base85

I was looking for an alternative to `Base64` which works fine on Unicode characters. I have found `ASCII85` which works great however I found no code or command doing that in `JS`.

I just found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058732/how-can-i-convert-a-guid-to-a-byte-array-in-javascript/2059893#2059893) which does not work for international characters and does not include decode function.

Here there are online [Decoder](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/ascii85_decode/)/[Encoder](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/ascii85_encode/).

Even found [codes](https://github.com/wermington/ASCII85_ENCODE_DECODE/blob/master/main.c) in C language doing that(I don't have enough JS data handling knowledge to convert).

And some [codes](https://bitbucket.org/dojo/dojox/src/8e0cd58e98ca/encoding/ascii85.js?at=default) that I don't know how to run.

I have heard that `JQuery` does support `Base64` but it seems that it does not support `Ascii85`.

Does somebody know anything about `Ascii85` in JS which might help?

thanks

Comment: The question is, why do you need Base64 to begin with, and why isn't UFT-8 good enough ?

Comment: What is wrong with UTF-8? Or any standard encoding?

Comment: I use ASCII85 not to leave direct access to a string array. It is better than obfuscation. it is not issue of security but issue of data rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using dojo.js framework     :

[Decode Example + source](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/html/entities/decode.html)

[Encode Example + source](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/html/entities/encode.html#dojox-html-entities-encode)

[ascii85 Encoding using](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/invaders/src/e49caaad10eb/js/lib/dojox/encoding/tests/compression/colors2.html)

summary:

```
dojo.require("dojox.encoding.ascii85");
var dc = dojox.encoding
var buf = dc.ascii85.decode("")
var a85 = dc.ascii85.encode("");
```

Comment: this is the same as what i mentioned in [one of the links](https://bitbucket.org/dojo/dojox/src/8e0cd58e98ca/encoding/ascii85.js?at=default). but how to use it?

Comment: it seems that your example is about html entity encoding and not ascii85!

Comment: you true , that is how to use encoding in general
see this link he used the same framework (he used encoding ascii85)
https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/invaders/src/e49caaad10eb/js/lib/dojox/encoding/tests/compression/colors2.html

Answer (score 9):

Pure JavaScript **Ascii85** AKA Base85 encoding/decoding functions:

```js
function encode_ascii85(a) {
  var b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k;
  for (!/[^\x00-\xFF]/.test(a), b = "\x00\x00\x00\x00".slice(a.length % 4 || 4), a += b, 
  c = [], d = 0, e = a.length; e > d; d += 4) f = (a.charCodeAt(d) << 24) + (a.charCodeAt(d + 1) << 16) + (a.charCodeAt(d + 2) << 8) + a.charCodeAt(d + 3), 
  0 !== f ? (k = f % 85, f = (f - k) / 85, j = f % 85, f = (f - j) / 85, i = f % 85, 
  f = (f - i) / 85, h = f % 85, f = (f - h) / 85, g = f % 85, c.push(g + 33, h + 33, i + 33, j + 33, k + 33)) :c.push(122);
  return function(a, b) {
    for (var c = b; c > 0; c--) a.pop();
  }(c, b.length), "<~" + String.fromCharCode.apply(String, c) + "~>";
}

function decode_ascii85(a) {
  var c, d, e, f, g, h = String, l = "length", w = 255, x = "charCodeAt", y = "slice", z = "replace";
  for ("<~" === a[y](0, 2) && "~>" === a[y](-2), a = a[y](2, -2)[z](/\s/g, "")[z]("z", "!!!!!"), 
  c = "uuuuu"[y](a[l] % 5 || 5), a += c, e = [], f = 0, g = a[l]; g > f; f += 5) d = 52200625 * (a[x](f) - 33) + 614125 * (a[x](f + 1) - 33) + 7225 * (a[x](f + 2) - 33) + 85 * (a[x](f + 3) - 33) + (a[x](f + 4) - 33), 
  e.push(w & d >> 24, w & d >> 16, w & d >> 8, w & d);
  return function(a, b) {
    for (var c = b; c > 0; c--) a.pop();
  }(e, c[l]), h.fromCharCode.apply(h, e);
}

var myString='This is a test!';
var encoded=encode_ascii85(myString);
var decoded=decode_ascii85(encoded);
document.write(decoded);
```

Comment: This example fails to restore unicode text: emoji, cyrillic at least.

Comment: It does not work correctly with binary strings, also with long strings (65k+ of chars)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [JavaScript ASCII85 (Base85) implementation](https://github.com/nE0sIghT/ascii85.js) which can work both with byte arrays and strings

Comment: Add some more desription here

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who would like a loquacious version of [Dave Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184813/how-to-encode-decode-ascii85-in-javascript/31741111#31741111) (reverse engineered from his answer and tested):

```
function encode_ascii85(sSource) {
    var sSuffix, iStringLength, f;
    var charArray = [];

    if (!/[^\x00-\xFF]/.test(sSource)) {
        [sSource, sSuffix, iStringLength] = initForLoop(sSource);

        for (var iIndex = 0; iStringLength > iIndex; iIndex += 4) {
            f = (sSource.charCodeAt(iIndex) << 24) + (sSource.charCodeAt(iIndex + 1) << 16);
            f = f + (sSource.charCodeAt(iIndex + 2) << 8) + sSource.charCodeAt(iIndex + 3);

            appendNextChar(f, charArray);
        }
        (function truncate(oArray, b) {
            for (var m = b.length; m > 0; m--) oArray.pop();
        })(charArray, sSuffix);

        return "<~" + String.fromCharCode.apply(String, charArray) + "~>";
    } else {
        // Error Handling
    }

    function initForLoop(a) {
        var sSuffix = "\x00\x00\x00\x00".slice(a.length % 4 || 4);
        return [a += sSuffix, sSuffix, a.length];
    }

    function appendNextChar(f, oArray) {
        if (f === 0) {
            oArray.push(122);
        } else {
            var g, h, i, j, k;
            k = f % 85, f = (f - k) / 85;
            j = f % 85, f = (f - j) / 85;
            i = f % 85, f = (f - i) / 85;
            h = f % 85, f = (f - h) / 85;
            g = f % 85;
            oArray.push(g + 33, h + 33, i + 33, j + 33, k + 33);
        }
    }
}

function decode_ascii85(sSource) {
    var sSuffix, d, iStringLength;
    var charArray = [];

    if ("<~" === sSource.slice(0, 2) && "~>" === sSource.slice(-2)) {
        sSource = initForLoop(sSource);

        for (var iIndex = 0; iStringLength > iIndex; iIndex += 5) {
            var x = "charCodeAt";
            var w = 255;

            d = 85 * 85 * 85 * 85 * (sSource[x](iIndex) - 33) + 85 * 85 * 85 * (sSource[x](iIndex + 1) - 33);
            d = d + 85 * 85 * (sSource[x](iIndex + 2) - 33) + 85 * (sSource[x](iIndex + 3) - 33) + (sSource[x](iIndex + 4) - 33);

            charArray.push(w & d >> 24, w & d >> 16, w & d >> 8, w & d);
        }
        (function truncate(oArray, b) {
            for (var m = b.length; m > 0; m--) oArray.pop();
        })(charArray, sSuffix);

        return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, charArray);
    } else {
        // Error Handling
    }

    function initForLoop(a) {
        var z = "replace",
            y = "slice";

        a = a[y](2, -2)[z](/\s/g, "")[z]("z", "!!!!!");
        sSuffix = "uuuuu" [y](a.length % 5 || 5);
        a += sSuffix;
        iStringLength = a.length;

        return a;
    }

}
```